# codeigniter echo HEBREW shows symbols

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter database config:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

My View File:

[image]

My Database:

[image]
[image]

I have added in my HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But still my html shows:

> ×™×—×™×“×” ×œ× ×ž×©×“×¨×ª

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the database.php file to different charset.

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';  
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting, put first query to be `SET NAMES utf8`.
Also, is file saved as utf8?